# Current and past meaning of "billion" in BrE

Tags: american-english, british-english, phrase-usage

According to the following extract from the ***[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/how-many-is-a-billion)*** "billion" in BrE used to mean "a million million", but its meaning has changed to the more common AmE usage meaning "a thousand million".

> - In British English, a billion used to be equivalent to a million million (i.e. 1,000,000,000,000), while in American English it has always equated to a thousand million (i.e. 1,000,000,000). ***British English has now adopted the American figure, though, so that a billion equals a thousand million in both varieties of English.***

The origin of this usage and its subsequent change, as explained by ***[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=billion)***, are  from French:

> - 1680s, from French billion (originally byllion in Chuquet's unpublished "Le Triparty en la Science des Nombres," 1484; copied by De la Roche, 1520); see bi- "two" + million. A million million in Britain and Germany (numeration by groups of sixes), which was the original sense; ***subsequently altered in French to "a thousand million" (numeration by groups of threes) and picked up in that form in U.S.,***  "due in part to French influence after the Revolutionary War" [David E. Smith, "History of Mathematics," 1925].
> - ***France then reverted to the original meaning in 1948***. British usage is truer to the etymology, but U.S. sense is said to be increasingly common there in technical writing.

As far as I can remember (1980s), a billion, at least in finance, has always meant a thousand million, and I've never come across its older usage.

Questions:

- When did  BrE adopted the  AmE usage of a billion?
- What was "a thousand million" called in BrE when a billion meant "a milliom million"?

Comment: The answer to part of your question is [milliard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/milliard).  Can't help with the rest.

Comment: The last question is answered by "It was called a thousand million".

Comment: It has happened in my lifetime which began during WW2. I started off thinking of a billion as a million million. @cobaltduck The French have stuck with *milliard* for what we now call *billion*, and their *billion* is what we call *trillion*. Must get confusing for people who number their wealth with more than nine noughts!

Comment: @Andrew Leach - you are saying that it was not called "a milliard"?

Comment: @JOSH Personally I don't recall the word *milliard* being used in English, though the OED has multiple examples of it: *1974   Encounter 43 iv. 58/2   English schoolchildren are still taught that a thousand million is a milliard.1990   Man 25 95   Milliards of deities assembled in front of the cave.* I would guess that it was in the mid-seventies (effects of globalisation?) that in Britain we switched to the American billion. 


*

Comment: @J I'm with WS2: never ever heard it. It did crop up while learning French.

Comment: I have old copies of the Guinness Book of World Records that refer to quantities in this range as "x,000 million" and claim that the only true _billionaire_ (what I'd call a _trillionaire_) in the world up to that time was J. Paul Getty.

Answer (score 3):

Britain officially changed to the short scale system in 1974

source: http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/written_answers/1974/dec/20/billion-definition#S5CV0883P0_19741220_CWA_439

However, I would assume that the American usage had gained quite some popularity before this point otherwise its adoption wouldn't have been necessary.

The term you are looking for is milliard.

Comment: The American usage certainly had gained quite some popularity before that point. I clearly remember my father explaining the whole thing as soon as I was old enough to understand it, in about 1962 - so a dozen years before that point.

Answer (score 0):

I can't back this up, but I wonder if it is linked to increasing use of engineering notation and metric prefixis, which would make it more important to have a specific name for every multiple of a thousand. This would make "thousand million" undesirable, forcing a choice between adopting the American billion and the French milliard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that a billion was a million million, but gave up on that years ago due to American usage. It's now a thousand million, or 10^9, or in old language, a milliard.

Usage of milliard would appear to have been declining since the 60s, as suggested by google ngrams:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=milliard&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmilliard%3B%2Cc0

As an academic writer I would say that there's no clear cut-off. Older people will continue to complain about incorrect usage; younger people will continue to adopt the newer terminology -- until the old people die.